# Iterating over the possible flows in a bipartite graph

Tags: c, algorithm, graph, bipartite

Consider a directed bipartite graph where both vertex sets A and B have m weighted vertices. Edges go only from A to B, and All vertices in A have the same degree which we denote n. The vertex weights are upper bounded by their degree.

As an example, consider m = 4 and n = 2, so we have A and B with 4 vertices each, and two edges from each vertex of A going to B. All weights on vertices in A are upper bounded by 2.

I am interested to loop over all possible edge flows from A to B, and in particular the resulting weights of vertices in B. I want to do this as efficiently as possible in C, and in particular with little memory, as I will be using this as a sub-routine in a depth-first-search.

I really hope for your clever inputs :)

Edit: All edges have a capacity of 1

Comment: Recursion may be the easiest way to accomplish this task. However, it is not at all memory efficient.

Comment: I would especially want to avoid recursion as it will already be part of a larger recursive algorithm

Comment: What do you want to achieve? Obtain all possible weights of every vertex in `B` or some optimal condition?